# bug-input 2d array using scanf in C

Tags: c, arrays

Whats wrong with this?I am getting segmentation fault during runtime.

```
int size;
scanf("%d",&size);
int init[size][size];
 //initial matrix
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
     scanf("%d",init[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `&init[i][j]` rather than `init[i][j]` in `scanf()`.

Comment: it works but i thought init[i][j] also points to address of init[i][j].

Comment: I think you mix it us with pointer arithmetics. init+i*size+j indeed will be *int, but init[i][j] will give you array element, which is int.